# Adding my own signing certificate to the UAC exclusion list?

Tags: uac

On Windows 7, applications signed by "Microsoft Windows Publisher" don't prompt for elevation when UAC is turned on.

Is there any way that I can add my own code-signing certificate to the UAC exclusions list, to get the same behaviour?

I've got a couple of utilities that I always want to run elevated, so if I could sign them myself and install my self-signed CA certificate somewhere, and then bypass the UAC prompt, that'd save me time every morning when I log in.